# How to replace values in a column based on a condition in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-update

Apologies if this is a silly questions as I am fairly new to SQL.

I have a table (`TEST`) with 3 columns; all three columns are ID columns.

I want to replace the values in column `A` with the values in column `B` if the values in column `B` are *not* `NULL`.

If values in column B are `NULL` I want to replace the values in column `A` with the values of column `C`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the common *"when column IS NULL then use some other value"* requirement SQL DBMS provide several options - typically functions  e.g. `IFNULL()`, `NVL()`, `COALESCE()`.

`COALESCE` is a good choice in this case as it is concise and maps to the requirement in a direct way: it returns the value of the first input parameter - starting from the left-most - that is *not* `NULL`.

Combined with the `UPDATE` command the desired effect can be created with:

```sql
UPDATE test
   SET a = COALESCE(b, c);
```

**Hint:** in order to pre-view what the result of the `UPDATE` statement will look like, one can always write a corresponding `SELECT` statement:

```sql
SELECT a
     , b
     , c
     , COALESCE(b, c) AS new_a
FROM 
    test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Create TABLE #temp (
Col_A nvarchar(10),
Col_B nvarchar(10),
Col_C Nvarchar(10)
)

insert into #temp values ('a', 'b', 'c')
insert into #temp values ('aa', null, 'cc')
insert into #temp values ('aaa', null, 'ccc')
insert into #temp values ('aaaa', 'b', 'ccccc')

UPDATE #temp  SET Col_A = CASE WHEN Col_B is Not Null THEN Col_B ELSE Col_C END;
SELECT * from #temp
Drop TABLE #temp
```